# How to show shimmer effect on cards which is placeholder of SVG network images in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, card, shimmer

I haven't seen which describes the answer for my question in stackoverflow.

Here is some workaround

1. Add `shimmer: ^latestversion` to your `pubspec.yml` file.
2. Import the package `import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';` in your dart file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SvgPicture.network( width: 130.w,
'https://fromnetwork.svg',
 placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
   Container(
    child: Shimmer.fromColors(
           baseColor:Colors.grey[300]!,
           highlightColor:Colors.grey[100]!,
           child:
                shimmerCard())),
          ),

Widget shimmerCard() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
```

this will give shimmer loading on cards till the svg images downloads from network

Comment: this package https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer